# What happen when we enter tab before completing the query?

Tags: psql

When we enter tab without completing the query with `;`, what exactly happens? Does it affect the database if we e.g. perform an `update` like this?

```
psql> update students set   where roll_no=23  (entered tab)
```

As result, the actual result of the query appears.

When we do the following:

```
psql> update students set   where roll_no=23
```

When used inside `begin .. commit` and without `begin ... commit`
Result is a warning and the command is not affecting the database.

Comment: You just enter a tab, that's all. As long as you don't end the statement with `;` it won't be executed.

Comment: No warning is shown just repeats the code.what happens if we break the query in-between Ctrl+C/Z ? when used without begin ... commit .